# ASP .NET CORE 5 Changing authentication for an existing project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an existing project which is getting pretty large. I need a registration/login system in it which there is not. When I have created the project I did not select any Authentication option. Can I implement a login system now please?

Thank you

Comment: I would consider Azure b2c

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Azure Active Directory B2C` to achieve this, But some features in `Azure` are charged. Refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview) to learn more about **auze ad b2c**

If you don't want to use `Azure`, You can `Scaffold Identity` in your existing project, It will generate an identity system, And You can also choose to generate the page(**register/login/logout/...**) whitch you need.

Refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) and follow the stpes what it mentioned to generate your identity system.

Comment: Azure is pretty big, so saying `use Azure` is about as helpful as saying `use computers`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific